# Ways of Creating an object instance and associated properties

Tags: c#, oop

I usually initiate an instance of an object and associate some Properties like this.

```
      RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel();
        registerModel.UserName = userName;
        registerModel.OpenID = openID;
        registerModel.Password = password;
        registerModel.ConfirmPassword = confirmPasswod;
```

I found verbose repeating the instance name for each property.

Could you show alternative ways (probably more elegant that mine) to achieve the same result?

I'm new at programming so an example of code would be great thanks

Comment: I'm no expert in C#, but a constructor? Maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx):

```
RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel
{
  UserName = userName,
  OpenID = openID,
  Password = password,
  ConfirmPassword = confirmPasswod
};
```

Other way would be to do it via constructor.